How do I get values from the first 'n' minute candle in pinescript?
I am trying to get the values of the very first 15 minute candle like this. But I get an error. Would appreciate some directions.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

[o,h,l,c] = barstate.isfirst?request.security('','15',[open,high,low,close]):na 

var table t = table.new(position = position.bottom_right,columns = 2,rows = 4,bgcolor = color.gray,border_color = color.white)

if barstate.islast and not na(o) and not na(h) and not na(l) and not na(c)
    table.cell(t,0,0,'open', text_color =  color.white)
    table.cell(t,0,1,'high', text_color =  color.white)
    table.cell(t,0,2,'low', text_color =  color.white)
    table.cell(t,0,3,'close', text_color =  color.white)

    table.cell(t,1,0,str.tostring(o), text_color =  color.white)
    table.cell(t,1,1,str.tostring(h), text_color =  color.white)
    table.cell(t,1,2,str.tostring(l), text_color =  color.white)
    table.cell(t,1,3,str.tostring(c), text_color =  color.white)

Error: Cannot call 'operator ?:' with argument 'expr1'='call 'request.security' ([series float, series float, series float, series float])'. An argument of '[series float, series float, series float, series float]' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected.
